# Problem in understanding solution to a Question?

Tags: functions

The solution to one of the question in my test book is as followed

> $$\tan^{-1}(x^2 - 18x + a) > 0$$
>   $$x^2 - 18x + a > 0$$
>   $$(18)^2 - 4a < 0 \implies a> 81$$

problem is that i am not able to understand the transformation from line 2 to line 3 can anyone explain it to me

Thanks

Akash

Comment: The third line is the discriminant of the LHS of the second line.

Comment: oh thanks i never saw that thanks @muffle and J.W. Perry

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear, we want $a$ such that $\arctan(x^2-18x+a) > 0$. Note that typically the range of $\arctan(y)$ is $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2, \dfrac{\pi}2\right)$. Hence, $\arctan(x^2-18x+a) > 0 \implies x^2 - 18x + a > 0$ for all $x$. We can rewrite this as $$x^2-2 \cdot 9 \cdot x + 9^2 - 9^2 + a > 0 \text{ for all }x$$
Hence, we need
$$(x-9)^2 + a-81 > 0 \text{ for all }x$$
From this, we can conclude(why?) that $a-81 > 0 \implies a > 81$.